# TS2740:(TS) Type 'VNode' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 283 more

Tags: typescript

`Type 'VNode' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 283 more.

```
> import { init, classModule, propsModule, styleModule, eventListenersModule, h} from 'snabbdom';
> const patch = init([classModule, propsModule, styleModule, eventListenersModule]);
> let tasks: string[] = [];
> function view() {
> return h('div#app', [
> h('input#new-task', {
> props: { type: 'text', placeholder: 'Add a new task' },
>         }),
> h('button', { on: { click: addTask } }, 'Add Task'),
> h('ul#task-list', tasks.map((task, index) =>
> h('li', { key: index }, task)
>         )),
>     ]);
> }
> function addTask() {
> const newTask = (document.getElementById('new-task') as HTMLInputElement).value;
> if (newTask.trim() !== '') {
> tasks.push(newTask);
> updateView();
>         (document.getElementById('new-task') as HTMLInputElement).value = '';
>     }
> }
> function updateView() {
> const newVNode = view();
> patch(oldVNode, newVNode);
> oldVNode = newVNode;
> }
> let oldVNode = document.getElementById('app') || document.body;
> updateView();
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add void in updateview() function then will work.